# Overloading + operator and avoiding incompatibility

Tags: r

I was trying to overload + operator and ran into incompatibility issues. Even though + is an S3 generic function, it seems to look at both arguments (similar to a multiple dispatch) instead of just the left argument like other S3 generic functions (see Groups "Ops" at http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/summary). So, if two different + functions are defined for the arguments, R issues a warning and falls back to + for two numeric values.

Here is an example:

```
myType1 <- function(obj) {
  structure(obj, class = "myType1")
} # function myType1

`+.myType1` <- function(obj1, obj2) {
  return(obj1)
} # function +.myType1

myType2 <- function(obj) {
  structure(obj, class = "myType2")
} # function myType2

`+.myType2` <- function(obj1, obj2) {
  return(obj2)
} # function +.myType2

myType1("A") + 1 # this works, use defined types seem to have precedence
myType1("A") + myType2(1) # this doesn't
```

Is there a way to get around this problem? I know that S4 methods support multiple dispatch. Will using S4 help me avoid this problem, even if an S3 + method is defined for one of the arguments?

Thank you so much in advance.

Sincerely,
Junghoon Lee

Comment: Have a look at the code of `+.Date` and `+.POSIXt`. If you want to use S3, you can use `if` conditions that check if unary or binary `+` is used and check the class of both arguments.